# If statement in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

How can i write correctly this code, in such a way that it is a valid if syntax, and if it is not respected, should I have someone else with it?

Basically I want to search for a text in a popup window. If it does not exist, enter the code in else statement.

```
cy.get(".ibxudA").find('.WildnessText-kRKTej').should('have.text',"Wildness")
```

Comment: Is the text you are searching for a key aspect of your test(s)?

Answer (score 2):

You can yield the subject returned by `find` and evaluate the text using JQuery commands.

```js
cy.get('.ibxudA').find('.WildnessText-kRKTejj').then(($el) => {
  if ($el.text() !== "Wildness") {
    // code to execute if it does not have the text
  } else {
    // code to execute if it does have the text
  }
});
```